# How to translate "Sort by" region of the KickStart commerce into Russian?

Tags: commerce

How to translate "Sort by" region of the KickStart commerce into Russian?

Need to completely translate KickStart commerce. Are there any ways except translating the core and searching for .po for an every single left module?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To translate "Sort by" region:

1. Go to the "Display products" view edit at path admin/structure/views/view/display_products/edit
2. In edit view page of the view you will find "Edit View Name/Description" dropdown menu on the right, from dropdown select "Translate View".

On the translate page, you will get fields to translate view stings.

Comment: There is no "Translate View", what to do? thx

Comment: @VassiaAlk I hope you are using entity translation or i18 modules to translate your website.
While using them, if you will enable "Views translation (i18nviews)", you will get the "Translate view" menu.